# why svg can't display when I use svg-sprite-loader in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, svg, svg-sprite-loader

[browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCr44.png)

I try to use svg-sprite-loader with Vue, but there's something wrong.
It seems like the svg file had been loaded at the start of the <body>, but there is nothing under the <use> tag

index.js and iconSvg.vue are under /views/icons/
*.svg files under /views/icons/svg/

and source files:
index.js

```js
const req = require.context('./svg', false, /\.svg$/);
const requireAll = requireContext => {
  return requireContext.keys().map(requireContext);
}
requireAll(req);
```

iconSvg.vue

```
<template>
<div>
  <svg :class="svgClass" aria-hidden="true">
    <use :xlink:herf="iconName"></use>
    </svg>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { computed, reactive } from 'vue';

export default{
  name: "iconSvg",
  //props: ['iconClass', 'className'],
  props: {
    iconClass: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
      },
    className: {
      type: String,
      default: ""
    }
  },
  setup(props) {
    
    const iconName = computed(() => `#icon-${props.iconClass}`);
    const svgClass = computed(() => {
      if (props.className)
        return `svg-icon ${props.className}`;
      else
        return `svg-icon`;
    });
    return {
      iconName,
      svgClass
    };
  },
}
</script>
```

main.js

```js
import { createApp, component } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import store from './store';
import ElementPlus from 'element-plus';
import 'element-plus/lib/theme-chalk/index.css';
import "./views/icons/index.js"
import iconSvg from "./views/icons/iconSvg.vue";
//import VueCompositionApi from '@vue/composition-api'

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(store).use(router).use(ElementPlus).mount('#app');
app.component('icon-svg', iconSvg);
```

vue.config.js

```js
//a part of the full file
//and i use 'runtimeCompiler: true,' when I start build a component
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    const svgRule = config.module.rule("svg");
    svgRule.uses.clear();
    svgRule
      .test(/\.svg$/)
      .use('svg-sprite-loader')
      .loader('svg-sprite-loader')
      .options({
        symbolId: 'icon-[name]',
      }).end();
   }
```

Comment: xlink:herf seems like a typo

Comment: thanks! that waste me for three hour...